# Join and count in sql-alchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a model defined like so:

```
class Article(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    authors = db.relationship('Author', secondary=articles_authors, backref=db.backref('articles', lazy='dynamic'))
    tags = db.relationship('Tag', secondary=articles_tags, backref=db.backref('articles', lazy='dynamic'))
    comments = db.relationship('Comment', backref=db.backref('article'), lazy='dynamic')
    creation_time = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)
    modification_time = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)
    title = db.Column(db.String(256), nullable=False)
    contents = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
```

I'd like to create a query that would give me all articles joined with authors and tags and that would count comments related to the given article. That's what I figured out so far:

```
Article.query.options(db.joinedload(Article.authors), db.joinedload(Article.tags)).all()
```

What gives me trouble is the counting part - I couldn't find any examples on how to do it. So how do I do it?

EDIT:

Query that doesn't work, but feels like the right direction:

```
subquery = db.session.query(Comment.article_id, func.count(Comment.id).label('comments_count'))\
            .group_by(Comment.article_id).subquery()

return db.session.query(Article, subquery.c.comments_count)\
    .outerjoin(subquery, Article.id == subquery.c.article_id)\
    .join(Tag).all()
```

The counting part in this case works ok, but I'm not getting tags and authors using this query.

EDIT2:

If it's not obvious - relation between article and tag is many-to-many:

```
articles_tags = db.Table('articles_tags',
    db.Column('tag_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('tag.id')),
    db.Column('article_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('article.id'))
)
```

The same goes for article and author.

EDIT:

The answer:

```
subquery = db.session.query(Comment.article_id, func.count(Comment.id).label('comments_count'))\
            .group_by(Comment.article_id).subquery()

return db.session.query(Article, subquery.c.comments_count)\
    .outerjoin(subquery, Article.id == subquery.c.article_id)\
    .options(db.joinedload(Article.authors), db.joinedload(Article.tags)).all()
```

Comment: Why are you using `joinedload` instead of `join`? What exactly do you want to count?

Comment: About `joinedload` vs `join` - don't know man :). I just started learning flask + sqlalchemy and I find it very confusing. I want to pull out the information about articles - who wrote given article, what tags are assigned to it, how many comments does article have.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think what you are looking for might be something like this(?)

```
(
    session.query(Article, func.count(Comment.id))
    .select_from(Comment)
    .join(Comment.article)
    .group_by(Article)
)
```

To get the authors and tags you should be able to just use `.authors` or `.tags` on the `Article` objects. To load it eagerly, you could use joinedload or subqueryload.

**EDIT:**

```
(
    session.query(Article, func.count(Comment.id))
    .select_from(Comment)
    .join(Comment.article)
    .options(db.joinedload(Article.authors), db.joinedload(Article.tags))
    .group_by(Article)
)
```

Comment: Could you please take a look at my updated question?

Comment: Could you try using `.authors` or `.tags` on the returned `Article` objects using my query? Each of those will have to be a subquery internally because it's not a flat structure, because it's many to many

Comment: Although your answer was not entirely ok for me, it pushed me to a good track, so I'm accepting it. Thanks!

Comment: Does the second query work for you? It seems redundant to query the ids and then make query for object again, unless you get an error.

Comment: The second query doesn't work - column "article.id" has to appear in group by clause...

Comment: That's weird though. That problem only happens in cases with inheritance. Querying Article object in the background queries `*`. What if you add `Article.id` to the `group_by`?

Comment: Then it tells me that I should use author.id, and so on.

Comment: It might make sense then to query only fields that you need from `Article` and add those to the `group_by` as well, but I don't see why this doesn't work.